# How do I resolve "editor placeholder in source file error"

Tags: xcode

I'm coding for a table view, and this is recurring. Here's my code:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ungRU.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

The grey text is a placeholder that Xcode adds you need to replace it with your own value.